# Adding shared folders with Virtual Box

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I thought I should ask this as another question since the last screen is filling up.

I was able to install Linux Mint ver.10/Julia with Virtual Box.  My problem now, is that I am still trying to run the tbaMUD program that is on my host OS - Windows 7.  I accessed the help files included with the virtual box help menu and was able to add the guest additions that allow me to link a folder from my host OS to my guest OS.
I can see it under Devices\Share Folders but I am unable to access the files and folders under this mounted folder.  I am able to edit the folder, which lets me mount or add a new folder, or I can delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VirtualBox creates a guest user group called vboxsf, and you need to be a member of that group to access the folder.

You can add your Mint user account to the group through Menu->Control Center->System->Users and Groups. Select Manage Groups, scroll down to vboxsf, and select properties. Then check the accout that you're adding to the group.

After this is done, you should be able to access the Windows 7 folder. From there, I recommend copying the tbaMUD files to a local Linux folder before installing. It will help avoid any build issues that may appear based on file paths. Then you can follow the readme.unix install instructions, located here: [tbaMUD online docs](http://tbamud.com/websvn/listing.php?repname=tbaMUD&path=/doc/#_doc_)

Comment: Oh cool, thanks for the link.  I couldn't find that.

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxadd setup`

This will fix the issue that DKMS wasn't installed before you installed the Linux Guest Additions.

Comment: I don't know what I did wrong.  The Windws 7 folder Iwant Linux to access is C:\mine. When I typoe this, it names it mine.  I have tried cd mine and c C:\mine in the regular prompt under the terminal and after typing cd ..  I get the message that this file doesn't exist.

Comment: According tothe help file, this folder should be under my media directory, but it is not.  I am about to burn it to burn this file to a disk and try to copy it into the Virtual box.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work.  After I did the sudo command, I reinstalled the guest additions and was able to access the shared files.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  To educate myself, was the final fix just running the sudo command + reinstall, or did you have to also add your user to the vboxsf group?

Comment: @Chris Ting - not trying to answer your question... see the note in sec. 4.3.2 of the VBox help for info on vboxsf.

Comment: @Joe:  I know about the vboxsf group.  I've only seen people caught by not installing DKMS.  That's probably because vboxsf is in the shared folders section, while DKMS is in the Guest Additions section.  I'm just checking with the asker to further my knowledge of where people get stuck.